# ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - Migration from 2.1.8.RELEASE to 2.7.7

Tags: spring-boot

After migration from 2.1.8.RELEASE to 2.7.7, I get this error: **ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet. Unsupported class file major version 61**

I checked java 17 is used.

The piece of code causing this error is :

```
public class ApplicationWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    /**
     * set a default to use when no profile is configured.
     */
    DefaultProfileUtil.addDefaultProfile(application.application());
    return application.sources(MyApp.class);
    }
  }
```

Comment: ASM's `ClassReader` is shaded in spring-core, so this could mean that your application depdends on an outdated Spring Framework version. Could you check your application build and list all dependencies, especially spring-core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to an outdated Spring Framework version on your classpath. ASM's `ClassReader` is shaded in the spring-core module and the corresponding `spring-core` module with Spring Boot 2.7.x should support Java 17.

Running into this type of problems means that your application should probably apply the Spring Boot dependency management with [Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.2/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.parent-pom) or [Gradle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.2/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#managing-dependencies).